# Partialview result returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, actionresult, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Partial view does not return any data.When i check with debug tool on PartialView page(_ContentBlock.cshtml), model seem to null.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Module()
{
    int RouteDataValue = default(int);
    if (RouteData.Values["id"] != null)
    {
        RouteDataValue = int.Parse(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
    }

    using (Models.ContentModel db = new Models.ContentModel())
    {
        var Query = from n in db.PageModule
                       join m in db.Module on n.ModuleId equals m.ModuleId
                       where n.PageId == RouteDataValue
                       select m.PhysicalPath;

        return PartialView(Query.Single()); //returns PartialView such as ~/Modules/Content/_ContentBlock.cshtml
    }
}

public PartialViewResult ContentBlock()
{
    using (Models.ContentModel db = new Models.ContentModel())
    {
        return PartialView("~/Modules/Content/_ContentBlock.cshtml", db.ContentBlock.Where(n => n.PageId == 2).Single());
    }
}
```

**Page.cshtml**

```
@Html.Action("Module")
```

**_ContentBlock.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ContentBlock>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(n => item.Content)
}
```

Comment: With what debug tool are you checking that the model is null inside the `_ContentBlock.cshtml` partial? Also how is this action called? Are you using some AJAX call? Can you show your code?

Comment: Darin, i have updated my question.Yep, model is null inside _ContentBlock.cshtml.I am not using AJAX.

Comment: But how are you calling the controller action shown in your question? It is this controller action that is passing the model to the partial.

Comment: Darin, I know, I must call a partial view with Html.Action() method.But if you inspect my code (above), actually I am calling Partial view inside Partial View.Offfff :D I have confused :S

Comment: So you used `Html.Partial` instead of `Html.Action`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have used the `Html.Partial` helper instead of `Html.Action`. So you were basically only rendering the partial without ever hitting the controller action that is supposed to populate and the model to the partial.

Comment: Darin thank you,I have solved issue as @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName",Model)

Answer (score 1):

Your page `Page.cshtml` is calling the partial view action `Module` using:

```
@Html.Action("Module")
```

The action called `Module` is being executed.  In that action, your query results in a path to your view, such as:

```
"~/Modules/Content/_ContentBlock.cshtml"
```

That action is returning the single result of that query using:

```
return PartialView(Query.Single());
```

What this is doing is passing the name of the view to the `PartialView` method to return which view is going to be used to display data from the action.  In addition, no model data is included in this return.

That's where your problem is.  When you return the path to the partial view, you are simply telling the MVC system what view to use to display the data from `Module`.  It won't actually call **another** partial view.  That's not how it works.  So your model is null because, you didn't pass any data in your `PartialView(...)` call.

You have another action called `ContentBlock`.  But that action is not being called because nothing is calling it.

**Edit:**

Another problem you have is that `_ContentBlock.cshtml` uses a model of `IEnumerable<ContentBlock>`, but you're only passing it a `.Single()` from your `ContentBlock` action.